# I can't send a request by Firefox in iso-8859-1

Tags: ajax, jsp, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have an application in Java EE and I have my database in ISO-8859-1, thus I need do the jsp encoding in ISO-8859-1... (all my pages are in iso-8859-1)

I have a jsp with a javascript code, which does a request to a Struts action.

This is my js code.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    encoding:'iso-8859-1',      
    contentType: 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1',
    url: xUrl,
    success: function(){
        $("#MensajeOk").attr('style','display:block');
        $("#MensajeOk").delay(10000).slideUp(1000);
    }
});
```

with IE and Chrome all is correct, because it does the request coding in ISO-8859-1 but Firefox encodes the request in UTF-8 and this is a problem for me, because in server side I need ISO-8859-1 and with FF there are some characters than i can't recover.

mi form is

```
<html:form action="/action.do" acceptCharset="iso-8859-1"> 
<input type="text" name="title">
```

and my java code is

```
new String((request.getParameter("title")+"").getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"iso-8859-1"));
```

with it, I can recover fine the text with IE and Chome, but fails with Firefox.

Other option will be send the request in UTF-8 encoding by encodeURI('data') but in the server side I can't convert the text from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1...

Some idea???

Thanks a lot and sorry for me english!!

Comment: `new String(string.getBytes(encoding), encoding)` is a redundant roundtrip, equivalent to `string`, because `String.getBytes(encoding)` and `new String(bytes, encoding)` are inverse operations of each other.

Answer (score 1):

looking at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), there doesn't seem to be an option called `encoding` - but theres a nice little hint (including the solution to your problem) on the `contentType`-option:

> Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side.

so it seems like firefox is right and the other browsers do it wrong - try to remove the `encoding`-option and to a serverside conversion.

Comment: i've seen that encoding option doesn't exist, but if I add the contentType option, I'll recieve in server side the data in UTF-8, and I need it in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Have you even read whats stated there? adding `contentType ` won't make it any better - you _can't_ reliably set the charset for sending data with jquery. the only thing to do is removing `encoding` to make all browsers send utf-8 and then the a utf-8-to-ISO-8859-1 conversion on your server before processing the data.

Comment: I can do it... I can recieve the data in server in UTF-8 (POST send always the request in utf-88), but I can't or don't know how to convert from UTF-8 to ISO without lost data.

Comment: Your Java program needs a String, not bytes representing a string. You just need to call `request.getParameter()` and you will get a String decoded by the servlet engine. When you send the string to your database, your JDBC driver will take care of encoding it correctly for your database. The correct fix is to make sure your servlet engine and your JDBC driver both use the correct encoding. Your Java program should not do any manual encoding or decoding.